# Jquery AJAX if/else based on (this).attr()

Tags: jquery, dynamic, if-statement, load, recaptcha

My goal is to load a recaptcha only when the user clicks on the contact page link.

I have successfully built a site that uses navigation links to load external HTML content into the index page's main content div based on the following function:

```
$('div#index_content').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #content');
```

When user clicks a navigation link, content from one of 6 individual .html or .php files is loaded into the index.html container:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="fine_art.html" class="inactive">Fine Art</a></li>
        <li><a href="sketches.html" class="inactive">Sketches</a></li>
        <li><a href="props.html" class="inactive">Props</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php" class="inactive">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This all functions 100%.

The next step was to appended a function to the .load statement which loads a recaptcha into an empty div with id="captcha" for my contact form:

```
$('div#page_content').load(($(this).attr('href') + ' #contentB'), 
   function() {
     Recaptcha.create("my public key", "captcha"); 
   }
 );
```

The site is still functioning at this point, but the function calling the captcha runs every time one of the navigation links is clicked, and I would like to create an if() statement that only runs the recaptcha load function if the $(this).attr('href') is loading the contact.php content. In other words, I would like it to only load the captcha when the user clicks on "Contact" in the navigation bar.

I tried these two versions of my function but the captcha doesn't load in either case:

```
$('div#page_content').load(($(this).attr('href') + ' #contentB'), 
   function() {
       if ($(this).attr('href') == 'contact.php') {
               Recaptcha.create("my public key", "captcha"); 
       }
   }
 );
```

and...

```
$('div#page_content').load(($(this).attr('href') + ' #contentB'), 
   function() {
       var ifContact = $(this).attr('href');
       if (ifContact == 'contact.php') {
               Recaptcha.create("my public key", "captcha"); 
       }
   }
 );
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my if() statement? Does the $(this).attr('href') actually hold a value that can be equal to something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in the inner and outer function does not represent the same object, store the value of href outside the inner function and use that value in the inner function.

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('div#page_content').load(href + ' #contentB', 
   function() {
       if (href == 'contact.php') {
               Recaptcha.create("my public key", "captcha"); 
       }
   }
 );
```

Comment: You nailed it. And you have boosted my understanding of javascript/Jquery at the same time. Thanks!